# how to solve the equation

Tags: equation-solving

I want to sole the given equation for x. Can anyone help me please to analyse the solution. Thanks

```
6*L^2 - 9 B L x^3 - 2*L^2*x^4 + 3*B^2*x^6 + 2.5*B*L*x^7 + 2*x^8 - 
  0.5*B^2*x^10 == 0
```

Comment: Given what values for `B` and `L`? `Solve[f /. {L -> 4, B -> 2}, x]`

Comment: B and L can take arbitrary values, thanks for useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = 6*L^2 - 9 B L x^3 - 2*L^2*x^4 + 3*B^2*x^6 + 2.5*B*L*x^7 + 2*x^8 - 
     0.5*B^2*x^10 == 0 // Rationalize // Simplify

(* B L x^3 (18 - 5 x^4) + B^2 x^6 (-6 + x^4) + 4 L^2 (-3 + x^4) == 4 x^8 *)
```

Since the order of the polynomial (i.e., 10) is too great to express with radicals, the solution is given in terms of [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) objects

```
sol = Solve[eqn, x]

(* {{x -> Root[-12 L^2 + 18 B L #1^3 + 4 L^2 #1^4 - 6 B^2 #1^6 - 5 B L #1^7 - 
      4 #1^8 + B^2 #1^10 &, 1]}, {x -> 
   Root[-12 L^2 + 18 B L #1^3 + 4 L^2 #1^4 - 6 B^2 #1^6 - 5 B L #1^7 - 
      4 #1^8 + B^2 #1^10 &, 2]}, {x -> 
   Root[-12 L^2 + 18 B L #1^3 + 4 L^2 #1^4 - 6 B^2 #1^6 - 5 B L #1^7 - 
      4 #1^8 + B^2 #1^10 &, 3]}, {x -> 
   Root[-12 L^2 + 18 B L #1^3 + 4 L^2 #1^4 - 6 B^2 #1^6 - 5 B L #1^7 - 
      4 #1^8 + B^2 #1^10 &, 4]}, {x -> 
   Root[-12 L^2 + 18 B L #1^3 + 4 L^2 #1^4 - 6 B^2 #1^6 - 5 B L #1^7 - 
      4 #1^8 + B^2 #1^10 &, 5]}, {x -> 
   Root[-12 L^2 + 18 B L #1^3 + 4 L^2 #1^4 - 6 B^2 #1^6 - 5 B L #1^7 - 
      4 #1^8 + B^2 #1^10 &, 6]}, {x -> 
   Root[-12 L^2 + 18 B L #1^3 + 4 L^2 #1^4 - 6 B^2 #1^6 - 5 B L #1^7 - 
      4 #1^8 + B^2 #1^10 &, 7]}, {x -> 
   Root[-12 L^2 + 18 B L #1^3 + 4 L^2 #1^4 - 6 B^2 #1^6 - 5 B L #1^7 - 
      4 #1^8 + B^2 #1^10 &, 8]}, {x -> 
   Root[-12 L^2 + 18 B L #1^3 + 4 L^2 #1^4 - 6 B^2 #1^6 - 5 B L #1^7 - 
      4 #1^8 + B^2 #1^10 &, 9]}, {x -> 
   Root[-12 L^2 + 18 B L #1^3 + 4 L^2 #1^4 - 6 B^2 #1^6 - 5 B L #1^7 - 
      4 #1^8 + B^2 #1^10 &, 10]}} *)
```

Looking at the first two solutions,

```
Column[
 Plot3D[#, {L, -5, 5}, {B, -5, 5},
    WorkingPrecision -> 20,
    PlotPoints -> 50,
    MaxRecursion -> 2,
    ClippingStyle -> None,
    ImageSize -> 432,
    PlotLabel -> #,
    AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {L, B, x})] & /@ (x /. 
    sol[[1 ;; 2]])]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`ContourPlot3D` shows you possible real solution triples

```
ContourPlot3D[6*L^2 - 9 B L x^3 - 2*L^2*x^4 +3*B^2*x^6 + 2.5*B*L*x^7 + 2*x^8 -0.5*B^2*x^10 == 0, {x, -5, 5}, {B, 0, 3}, {L, 0, 3},AxesLabel -> Automatic, MaxRecursion -> 4]
```

in the `x,L,B`-space:

[image]